# Can a modern motherboard drives same size and same frequency memory modules at different timings simultaneously?

Tags: memory, memory-timings

I have a system with i7-10700K on Asus PRIME Z390-A motherboard with 2 x 16 GB DDR4-3200 (CMK32GX4M2B3200C16) with 16-18-18-36 timing.

I want to install additional 2 x 16 GB DDR4-3200 modules (CMK32GX4M2E3200C16), but the new pair has 16-20-20-38 timing instead of 16-18-18-36.

The Asus motherboard BIOS has tons of memory settings overrides; however I'm not sure if I can set it per module.  If I sets the overall setting to XMP or XMP II, will the motherboard drive the module at a common denominator (say 16-20-20-38) or at each module's precise timing?  Is it possible for the 16-18-18-36 module to be driven at 16-20-20-38?

Comment: "Is it possible for the 16-18-18-36 module to be driven at 16-20-20-38?" - `16-20-20-38` is actually is the exact timing all modules will run at.

Comment: @Ramhound Can we assume it will be okay for the 16-18-18-36 module to be driven at 16-20-20-38?

Comment: Your expectation does not make economic sense. The capability to use different timings would add hardware cost to the mobo. But it also means reduced performance, i.e. no N-channel memory operation.

Comment: As sawdust says, you lose performance due to losing dual-channel or triple channel modes whereby memory modules work together. As they are no longer at the same performance and no longer guaranteed to be able to send and receive data at the same timings you can no longer gang the memory up to double or triple the speed of a single module. It's conceptually similar to RAID 0 vs a JBOD array. RAID 0 gives you speed as long as you have two disks of identical size (latencies), while JBOD just chains whatever sized disks you have lying around. JBOD might make better use of the disks, but is slower.

Comment: @sawdust and Mokubai  I see. I was imagining since for each timing I have 1 pair, the mobo runs the memory at dual channel.  My thinking is that depending on the address of the memory being accessed, the mobo is smart enough to use the timing of the module where the memory region is being accessed.

Comment: @PaulS.Lee - Can faster memory run slower? **Yes** Was my original comment unclear? You will virtually see absolutely no performance differences between such a small delta in the timing. However, it’s a larger delta at the hardware level, so it’s unlikely you will be able to achieve a stable overclock

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the response.  I ended up having to relinqush the XMP setting, even though it is set to the lower timing (3200 MHz 16-20-20-38), since it fails test #6 in MemTest (Block move, 64 moves).  STILL, when I set it to "Auto" thus using the standard DDR4 JEDEC 2133 MHz, after a few hours, I got a Windows 11 kernel panic (blue screen with MEMORY_MANAGEMENT error).  I'm going to try identical 4 modules next time (still in order).

Comment: @Ramhound Turns out the issue is the BIOS needs an update that includes DRAM timing improvement.  Once I updated the BIOS, all 4 modules now working without error, even at XMP 3200 MHz !  The BIOS automatically selects the lower pair's timing: 16-20-20-38.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use one set of timings across all memory modules.

If you are selecting a memory configuration manually, which is often the case with XMP, you should make sure to select the looser timings, i.e. the ones with the larger numbers.

Running memory at looser timings is fine, but running tighter timings than it has been validated at may or may not work, and may lead to subtle stability issues.

Comment: Are you saying that modern DDR4 motherboards are still unable to run different module pairs at different speed?

Comment: @PaulS.Lee There is a single memory controller embedded as part of the CPU. At the higher speeds and lower latencies we keep pushing, the name of the game is simplicity. To accomplish what you are proposing would require massively increased complexity (and quite probably an extra buffer and therefore increased memory latency anyway!) for *everyone* to support an edge case scenario, where the solution instead is simple: if you want lower-latency RAM, buy a complete set of lower-latency RAM. If anything, DDR5 is increasingly preferring a 2-slot configuration to further increase signal integrity.

Comment: In any case, the latency difference between the modules you have is minimal and you'll likely never notice it anyway. Just run at the looser timings so it's nice and stable; you'll notice memory corruption long before you notice the likely <1% performance difference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.